# Creating Venn Diagrams with Categorical Data- matplotlib_venn

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I'd like to use Python 3 to make a Venn diagram to show categorical data.
If I do, say

```
  Rosy = ["chocolate", "chips", "cake", "sweets"]
  Steven = ["chocolate", "crisps", "nuggets"]

  venn2([set(Rosy), set(Steven)])
  plt.show()
```

Then I get a diagram with [the number of entries corresponding to each segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBgA6.png) but what I'd like is [the actual entries in each segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjIxI.png) (i.e. chips, cake sweets in the just Rosy bit, chocolate in the intersection and crisps and nuggets in Steven's bit). Is there any way of doing this using matplotlib_venn?

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I found is something like this:

```
set1 = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
set2 = set(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

v = venn2([set1, set2], ('Set1', 'Set2'))
v.get_label_by_id('10').set_text('\n A')
v.get_label_by_id('01').set_text('\n E')
v.get_label_by_id('11').set_text('\n \nB \nC \nD')
plt.show()
```

Just create functions that generate the texts from set1 & set2 for set_text on the fly and it's done.
[image]